# ARP атаки в логах касперского

Tags: windows-server-2012, arp, kaspersky

Есть сервер Windows Server 2012 сеть где то компов 50.
Сеть не управляемая.

В логах касперского на всех машинах периодически раз в секунду, три, пять, пол часа
в разное время сообщение обнаружена сетевая атака ARP с неизвестного источника
IP 0.0.0.24 B1:B2:B4:A0:0:0 или IP 0.0.0.47 mac не помню похож на предыдущий то же нули в конце, бывает атака с адреса пк, принтера, или какого нибудь устройства из сети.
Таких адресов 0.0.0.24 0.0.0.47 и маков как у них в сети нет.
Что за глюк?

Comment: Так это же arp атака, случайные mac/ip для нее норма. Но скорее всего какое то оборудование в сети глючит и производит битые пакеты с мусором

Comment: Вот то же такое подозрение потому что слишком странные IP